# Vehicle customs, lost passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, automobiles, mexico, lost-documents

My truck and I are US citizens. The truck permit for 6 months in Mexico cost $485. I must be at the border by 6/6 and I'm 8 hours away. The problem is I can't find my passport! What will happen? Can I check the truck out of Mexico without my passport so I don't loose $485? Do I have to leave Mexico or can I get another permit and deal with my lost passport at a consulate and avoid going into the states? What a mess...

Comment: Please clarify where you are, where your truck is, and what movement is required to avoid the loss.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan sorry, but did your read the question at least?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You want to get back to the USA to avoid renewing the permit for $485 however you've lost your passport. Are you wondering if you will be let back into the USA? A bona fide US citizen **cannot be denied entry into the USA** however if you don't have the right documents expect a lot of grilling and maybe detention while they verify your identity.

Comment: By the way your truck can't be a US citizen. :-)

Comment: He has to be able to *prove* that he's a US citizen.

Comment: @DJClayworth That is correct however a passport is not the only means of proof. There are cases where people have been verified through answering detailed questions about themselves and other secondary evidence.

Comment: My point was that while you write "expect a lot of grilling and maybe detention while they verify your identity", there is also some chance that you will *not* be admitted if you *can't* prove your identity.

Comment: thank you all for your advice...Here's what happened.. I went through the steps of 'cancelling' the 6 month vehicle permit turning in papers and scraping the sticker off the window as I was returning to the US. The cost was rolled back onto my card. At the US border, I explained to the officer that I couldn't find my passport. With my current driver's license confirmed by my vehicle registration and after the dog sniffed his approval, I was welcomed back with a friendly scolding to be more careful with my important papers!

Comment: @tasha you should add that as a self-answer.  [Self-answers are encouraged](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2):

OP provided feedback on the experience:

> Here's what happened. I went through the steps of 'cancelling' the 6-month vehicle permit, turning in papers and scraping the sticker off the window, as I was returning to the US. The cost was rolled back onto my card. At the US border, I explained to the officer that I couldn't find my passport. With my current driver's license, confirmed by my vehicle registration, and after the dog sniffed his approval, I was welcomed back with a friendly scolding to be more careful with my important papers!