# Are US citizens obligated to disclose foreign citizenships to US border patrol upon entry?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, legal, us-citizens, dual-nationality

I am a United States citizen. However, I reside in the Middle East. Upon hearing this, a US border patrol officer asked me to disclose to him all other citizenships that I hold.

I know that US border patrol has the right to determine an individual’s admissibility to the United States. However, given that I am a US citizen, could I be arrested/denied entry if I do not wish to disclose my other nationalities for privacy reasons?

Comment: No US Citizen can be denied entry into the USA. [This has been established in case law](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100664/can-a-us-citizen-use-a-passport-copy-to-enter-the-us-from-canada/100674#100674). You can be on a no fly list however once you manage to present yourself at US borders, you have a right to be let in regardless of whether you are a terrorist etc. On the other hand I **believe** they have the absolute authority to ask about your other citizenships. Remember that legally the USA merely _tolerates_ dual citizenship i.e. it winks and looks the other way.

Comment: @TheZealot dual citizenship is covered by the same case law. See Afroyim v. Rusk - its not because Department of State suddenly changed its position itself.

Comment: @GeorgeY. I don't think we are in disagreement. Afroyim v Rusk did not say the USA loves dual citizenship. It just said he could not be stripped of his US Citizenship involuntarily just because he is a citizen elsewhere. In my interpretation, it is tolerated. `The Afroyim decision opened the way for a wider acceptance of dual (or multiple) citizenship in United States law`. https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/Advice-about-Possible-Loss-of-US-Nationality-Dual-Nationality/Dual-Nationality.html

Comment: Is this question about Border Patrol (green uniforms, operate near the border but not at ports of entry) or CBP immigration inspectors (blue uniforms, examine passports at ports of entry and make admissibility decisions)?

Comment: If they indeed "have the absolute authority to ask about your other citizenships," what is the penalty for choosing not to disclose?  Seems somewhat analogous to court rulings that established a police officer may not demand identification without reasonable suspicion of a crime.

Comment: @WGroleau indeed.  They can ask, but they can't demand.  The problem with immigration officers, though, is that they don't seem to be well trained in this.  Even if the possession of other citizenships might be pertinent to some investigation they're legitimately pursuing, there's the fifth amendment (though, depending on the nature of the investigation, they could detain the person).  But it's hard to imagine how the question of additional citizenships would be relevant to any such investigation unless it's to explain the absence of stamps in the passport.

Comment: That last about stamps may actually be significant.  I was detained for a half-hour in BCN on a LHR-BCN-LIS-BOS trip after I had left Schengen by bus.  The official somehow didn't see the stamps for leaving Schengen and entering UK and asked "How can you be entering when you never left?"  Unsatisfied with my explanation, he parked me in a corner while he discussed with others what to do.  (Or maybe he merely took a half-hour break just to spite me.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question appears to be about Customs and Border Protection immigration inspectors rather than Border Patrol officers.  (Border Patrol is a distinct agency, although it is subordinate to CBP in the government's organizational chart.)

> Are US citizens obligated to disclose foreign citizenships to US border patrol upon entry?

No.

> I know that US border patrol has the right to determine an individual’s admissibility to the United States.

US citizens cannot be found inadmissible.  Grounds of inadmissibility apply only to aliens.  See 8 USC 1182.

> given that I am a US citizen, could I be arrested/denied entry if I do not wish to disclose my other nationalities for privacy reasons?

You cannot be denied entry.  You can be arrested if the arresting officer has a warrant or probable cause to suspect that you have committed a felony.  Now it's possible to imagine circumstances under which your not disclosing additional citizenships might reinforce an officer's suspicion that you have committed a crime, but by itself it cannot provide that suspicion, because of the fifth amendment.

In practice, of course, an immigration officer can make your life difficult by delaying your entry.  While they are not supposed to delay you on immigration grounds once they are convinced that you are a US citizen, they *can* delay you on customs grounds and they could probably even manufacture some uncertainty about your US citizenship if they were pressed to do so.  For example, they could claim to be looking into whether you had performed any of the statutory "expatriating acts" that could result in your losing US citizenship (but only if you perform the act with the intention of losing your US citizenship, and the government formally presumes that you have no such intention).

Finally, in short, it's not legal for them to demand an answer to that question, but they can nonetheless make your life difficult if you don't answer it.  There's no judge looking over the immigration officer's shoulder, and the only way for you to get the question before a judge is to file suit, a process that takes weeks to years.  At the end of a long flight, if you want to get home, your best course of action is probably to answer.

Comment: Many recent events show that what is illegal is not a reliable predictor of what will happen.

Comment: Under what conditions would an *immigration officer* perform a **customs inspection**? Dissatisfaction about an immigration specific question would normally not be a valid reason for a *customs officer* to perform a special customs inspection.

Comment: @MarkJohnson in the US they are essentially the same people. At airports there are separate zones set up for immigration and customs (before and after you get your bags, respectively) but the "immigration" officer usually does a preliminary customs inspection (asking if you have anything to declare, what you are bringing in) and I believe they can mark your declaration form to send you to secondary immigration or customs screening.

Comment: @ajd Has this changed in the last 5-10 years in the US? 
 Normally Customs is a distinct area of speciality, with special training in the area of taxes, duties but also in the area of agriculture and disease / health matters. Whereas Immigration is more similar to police tasks (inforcement of laws etc).

Comment: @MarkJohnson even before the creation of CBP, which merged immigration and customs inspectors into one agency, immigration officers would perform preliminary customs screening and processing of the customs declaration form. Even after the merger, individual officers will still be specialized in one area or another, especially at the larger ports.  But both immigration and customs inspectors are involved in the enforcement of laws; in fact far more people are arrested at ports of entry by customs inspectors.

Answer (score 3):

According to [ACLU](https://www.acluaz.org/sites/default/files/field_documents/aclu_border_rights.pdf):

> Agents at ports of entry may 
>   question people about their 
>   citizenship and what they are 
>   bringing into the country.
>   Even though you always have the 
>   right to remain silent, if you don’t 
>   answer questions to establish your 
>   citizenship, officials may deny you 
>   entry to the U.S. or detain you for 
>   search and/or questioning

So you must answer every question related to your **US citizenship** when you get to the border, but on every other question you may remain silent. What other citizenships you have is completely immaterial to your status as a US citizen and therefore CBP officers can't demand to know that information.

Comment: -1 It said *their* citizenship, doesn't necessarily have to mean only US citizenship. I'll change my vote if you offer more compelling evidence.

Comment: Once border guards have established that you are a US citizen they cannot deny you entry. So you have to answer enough questions to establish your US citizenship.

Comment: @DJClayworth given that a US passport is conclusive evidence of US citizenship, what other questions would they ask?

Comment: @ajd. A great question. "Did you steal this passport?" I suppose.

Comment: You haven't provided a link or a specific source so it's difficult to ascertain whether the context makes things clearer but in itself the quotes clarifies nothing. It's not even clear it pertains to what agents might ask to US citizens specifically.

Comment: @Relaxed added the source. Once CBP establishes you're a US citizen (presumably OP does have a passport to prove so), there's nothing they can do, unless of course you're carrying something forbidden in your luggage. Same rules apply in any country with protection against self-incrimination.

Comment: `What other citizenships you have is completely immaterial` -  Not exactly true. Your having other citizenship is evidence of allegiance to a foreign entity, what if it were North Korea or a country considered an adversary? Could be implied to mean you're more likely to harm the USA. Yes you will be let in because ultimately it is your right however the border control officer is there to also collect intelligence and the questioning helps glean that. It's not as simplistic as the ACLU wants you to believe, you can face significant harassment and detention, miss connecting flights etc.

Comment: The issue is that officials may also detain you for search and/or questioning for other reasons. You don't have to answer, but you won't necessarily like what happens after that, unless you're explicitly doing this with a plan of suing the government.

Comment: @TheZealot well, yes, CBP officers can certainly harass you. But if you believe that you having a second citizenship can be used against you in some way, you can keep your mouth shut and let them search your luggage for whoever long they want.

Comment: @JonathanReez Well, they cannot deny entry but they could presumably arrest you for some unrelated crime. As a little thought experiment, imagine you are carrying illegal drugs, there is certainly something they can do. So the question remains: Are they allowed to ask? Could you theoretically be arrested if you decline to answer? The basic point that US citizens cannot be turned away has already been made in a comment but that doesn't answer the question and your quote doesn't actually add anything to that.

Comment: @Relaxed It is absolutely legal for a US citizen to remain silent when questioned by any branch of the US government (that's the whole point of the fifth amendment). Whether or not CBP can harass you for your silence is beyond the scope of my answer.

Comment: @JonathanReez That's, however, the whole scope of the question.